# i want to take a value from entry but that didn't work

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, functools

the problem is:

```
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: b1_pg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e1'
```

i search entire google but i didn't found any thing

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x200+100+200')
def b1_pg(e1):
    search = str(e1.get())
    print(search)
    return search

what = ttk.Label(root, text="who do you want to search about???").grid(row=1, column=0)

e1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=40).grid(row=1, column=1)

b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="if you are ready prees here", command=b1_pg).grid(row=2, column=0)

#information=ttk.Label(root,text=family{search})

root.title('family')
root.mainloop()
```

i expect the code take the value from e1(entry) when i preesd the button but it give me an error

```
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: b1_pg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e1'
```

what's the wrong in my code?

Comment: Check there is enough elements in the `args` variable before you try [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) it

Comment: The function called by a button's `command=` option is not passed any parameters.

Comment: `el.get()` will always return none due to how you use `grid()`. You have to do `el.grid()` on a new line in order to use `get()` on `el`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things we need to correct here.

One issue that you use `grid()` on the same line you are defining the Entry field.
Because of this `e1` is actually going to always return `None` due to `grid()` being assigned in this way.

To fix this you can do `e1.grid()` on a new line and this will allow you to use `e1.get()` without issues.

That said lets correct your imports as `*` is bad in the sense you will end up overwriting methods.

So instead of doing:

from tkinter import *

Do this:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

We should also change a few things in your function.

The `return` section is not going to be doing anything of use here. You cannot return values to the button that called the function. It cannot be used in any way so you can remove that line. If you need to use that value somewhere then you can send it from the function to wherever you need it.

Related to your error in you question. There is no need for the argument `e1` in your function. You are not passing an argument to the function in the first place so this will cause an error. Second you are already calling e1.get() from the global namespace so there is no need for an argument.

Lastly you do not need to do `str(e1.get())`. The `get()` method is already returning a string. It will always return a string.

See below code and let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('family')
root.geometry('400x200+100+200')


def b1_pg():
    search = e1.get()
    print(search)


ttk.Label(root, text="who do you want to search about???").grid(row=1, column=0)
e1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
ttk.Button(root, text="if you are ready press here", command=b1_pg).grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```